# Getting error while reading salesforce custom field type Rich Textarea

Tags: coldfusion, salesforce, integration

I am using salesforce.cfc (downloded from Riaforge) to integrate coldfusion with salesforce.

```
<cfset latestProductList = salesforce.queryObject("SELECT Id, Name, Description__c, Price__c, ProductImage__c FROM Product__c") />
```

I have created one custom object named "Product__c". This object have one custom field "ProductImage__c" type "Rich TextArea". When i an trying to get product without this custom field it is run, but when i am trying to get product with this field i am getting below error:

"INVALID_FIELD: Name, Description__c, Price__c, ProductImage__c FROM Product__c ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:44 No such column 'ProductImage__c' on entity 'Product__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. "

But **i have this field. attached screen image of salesforce below.**

[image]

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Your error message has one underscore in the column name, `ProductImage_c`, but your query has two underscores.  Are you sure you're passing in the name correctly?

Comment: yes, i am passing correct name. I have added the query also in Question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Salesforce CFC, but can you just pass `SELECT *`?

Comment: @sam your error message suggests you are not passing 2 underscores in your query string. Is it possible the 2nd underscore is being replaced somewhere?

Comment: duncan, you can't SELECT * in Salesforce.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at Salesforce CFC shows that it hasn't been updated in a while.  The file SalesForce.cfc is pointing at:

https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/11.1

That's version 11.1 of the API, which is quite old and is long before rich text fields came into existence.

You *might* be able to fix this issue by simply updating the reference in SalesForce.cfc to the latest version of the API by changing

https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/11.1

to

https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/28.0

in that file, although there's a pretty good likelihood that that will break something else, since version 28.0 will have lots of new stuff that SalesForce.cfc is not coded to handle.

In any case, your problem is in fact the API version that you're using.  In cases like this, when a field type did not exist as of a certain API version, then that field is invisible for that version.  In your case, your rich text field is invisible for your API version, 11.1.

Comment: Thanks @amrcn. I did update the api as per your suggestion but it is giving me one more error "No operation available for request {urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com}login."

Comment: Yes that's the type of problem I'm referring to.  Unfortunately there probably isn't an easy fix for that -- this whole Salesforce package for ColdFusion needs updating, and it doesn't seem like anyone's home to do it.

Comment: ColdFusion is Java, so you might try using the much-more-current Java API tools like this one: https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc